# Network of Brokers - ActiveMQ - Any other alternatives?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, messaging, activemq-classic

We are setting up a pool/Network of ActiveMQ brokers. The issue we are having is that every broker instance should know who else is on the network. i.e we need to update the configuration(uri) xml when a new broker gets added to the pool and then release all the brokers. This is a time consuming process and seems like a over kill.

Is there a better approach? We thought of dynamic discovery, which needs multicast (not sure, whether it is supported)

Is there one place where we can update who is in the network, rather than in every broker instance?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network of Brokers with dynamic discovery using multicast is a standard example, please [see the network of brokers docs](http://activemq.apache.org/networks-of-brokers.html).

Also, dynamic rebalancing and updating of clients is supported (AMQ version >= 5.4) (`updateClusterClients`, `rebalanceClusterClients`), please [refer to failover docs](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html).

Comment: does dynamic rebalancing support message forwarding? If one broker which joined recently does not have any consumers, then can it forward the messages to other brokers?

Comment: @VanchinathanChandrasekaran: Yes, ActiveMQ networks use the concept of store and forward. Messages are stored in the local broker before being forwarded across the network to another broker. This means messages travel from broker to broker until they reach a consumer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have one last question. The failovers are updated dynamically on the client side. What happens when one of the producer or consumer fails and comes back. it will still connect to initial pool of brokers right? How it will know the new brokers that were added to the pool? given that the producer and consumer had a static failover configuration.

Comment: @VanchinathanChandrasekaran: Yes, with static configuration you will "fall back" to these values. If you now e.g. have a master broker that is not configured inside your client's failover url, the client can't find this broker.